# VS Code error with Prettier: "Invalid prettier configuration file detected... Cannot find module 'basedir=$(dirname..."

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, prettier, windows-11

I only get this error when I run VS Code 'as Administrator'. It isn't a problem when I run it normally, but I need to be 'as Administrator' to perform my tasks.

I'm currently getting errors any time I try to autoformat a file.

For example, if I try to use Format Document (Alt+Shift+F), the Prettier icon in the bottom left of my VS Code window shows red:

[image]

Clicking it opens the error log:

```
["INFO" - 5:19:55 PM] Formatting file:///c%3A/Users/MyUserName/Desktop/Code/diary-passle/Notes/W6/delete.json
["ERROR" - 5:19:55 PM] Invalid prettier configuration file detected.
["ERROR" - 5:19:55 PM] Cannot find module 'basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
case `uname` in *CYGWIN*|*MINGW*|*MSYS*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;; esac
if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then exec "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/prettier/bin-prettier.js" "$@" else exec node  "$basedir/node_modules/prettier/bin-prettier.js" "$@" fi'
Require stack:
- c:\Users\AdminUserName\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-9.10.4\node_modules\prettier\index.js
- c:\Users\AdminUserName\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-9.10.4\dist\extension.js
- c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js
- c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-amd.js
- c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-fork.js
...
```

I've checked the files listed in the 'Require stack', and those files are all present, so I don't understand what the issue is?

I've tried downloading prettier via `npm i prettier -g`. There are no local files such as `settings.json` or `.prettierrc` in my repository.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing VS Code from both my User and Admin accounts. I had to uninstall in Add/Remove Programs. I also had to remove some folders:

- Open Run (Win + R)
- Type %appdata%
- Press Enter
- Delete the folder `Code`

Also:

- Delete directory C:\Users<User Name>\AppData\Roaming\Code
- Delete directory C:\Users<User Name>.vscode

I had to remove folders in both accounts. I think the problem was there was some crossover between accounts that needed to be reset.